# What's wrong in my method to find values of $a$ and $b$ in the limit $ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(1+a\cos x)-b\sin x}{\sin^3x}=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(1+a\cos x)-b\sin x}{\sin^3x}=1$$

This was an example problem solved by my teacher first through L'Hopital's and then by series expansion.

I also proceeded through L'Hopital but ended with the wrong answer.

I divided the numerator and the denominator by $x$ to get:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+a\cos x)-b}{\sin^2x}=1$$

Since the numerator tends to zero for the limit to have a finite value, $b-a=1$

Then I divided the numerator and denominator by $x^2$ to get:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+a\cos x)-b}{x^2}=1$$

L'hopitals:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-a\sin x}{2x}=1$$

I get $a=-2$ but it's supposed to be $\dfrac{-5}{2}$

Which of my steps was wrong or illegal?

Comment: I do not understand your calculations. Somehow the $\sin (x)$ terms vanish when you divide by $x$ or by $x^2$.

Comment: How did you cancel the $\sin(x)$ terms in the first limit?

Comment: @MartinR $lim_{x\to 0} \sin x/x=1$ is a standard limit, no?

Comment: To divide top and bottom you have to first factor out x from the top before cancelling. You didn't.

Comment: You can impose limits only once in your entire computations. Replacing sinx by x is not appropriate by imposing limits midway.

Comment: @Ilovemath oh... can you link me to somewhere I can read more on why that's not allowed? This step is done quite commonly in my given booklet.

Comment: When $\sin x$ is "replaced" by $x$, the rationale is that higher order terms of the Taylor expansion $$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}$$ do not affect the final answer. In your limit, however, the terms up to the order $x^3$ contribute to it. (This is because both the numerator and the denominator behave like a multiple of $x^3$ as $x\to\infty$.) That is why you can't use the naïve approximation $\sin x \approx x$. Rather, you may use $\sin x \approx x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$, especially for the $\sin x$ in the numerator.

Comment: (In my previous comment, $x\to\infty$ should be replaced by $x\to0$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which of my steps was wrong or illegal?

This one is wrong.

> I divided the numerator and the denominator by $x$ to get:
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+a\cos x)-b}{\sin^2x}=1$$

Once you split the limits using their algebra, clubbing them again may give
wrong answer.

The correct method using L.H. rule will be

First multiply and divide by $x^3$ and separate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3}{\sin^3x}=1$ to get

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(1+a\cos x)-b\sin x}{x^3}=1\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-(b-a)\cos x -ax\sin x}{3x^2}=1$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-(b-a)\cos x}{x^2}-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a\sin x}{x}=3$$

For the first limit to exist , $b-a=1$ which gives

$$\frac{1}{2}-a=3\implies a=-\frac{5}{2}\implies b=-\frac{3}{2} $$